# How to set environment variable in a Jenkins build?

Tags: node.js, jenkins, environment

I have a node server that uses environments variables.

I manually add those to my .bashrc file and when the node server runs, it uses them as process.env.something.

Now we have to deploy this service from a Jenkins job.

What is the proper way of setting this up?

Comment: have you checked this jenkins plugin? https://plugins.jenkins.io/config-file-provider/

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about setting the environment variable during the run of the Pipeline then you can use Declarative for it.

```
  environment {
    PROJECT_NAME = 'Jenkins-Job'
    DISABLE_AUTH = 'true'
  }
```

Environment variables can be set globally, like the example below, or per stage.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'linux'
    }

    environment {
        DISABLE_AUTH = 'true'
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            environment {
               DB_ENGINE    = 'sqlite'
            }
            steps {
                echo "Database engine is ${DB_ENGINE}"
                echo "DISABLE_AUTH is ${DISABLE_AUTH}"
                sh 'printenv'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For more info, please read [this](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#using-environment-variables)

Comment: just  to make sure we are on the same page, during the node server run, the value of DISABLE_AUTH will be able to checked as process.env.DISABLE_AUTH?

That is what I am really after, the node service happy the ability to check for that variable same as if it was defined in .bashrc

Comment: Hi. DISABLE_AUTH value will be accessible as $DISABLE_AUTH